# How to build a Dialogflow agent with open questions?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I'm new to Dialogflow, I ask for your help to try to build an open question.

I'm doing a customer satisfaction survey and I want to end it with a question like "Lastly, I'd like to know if you have any feedback on your experience with this process"

Here the user can write anything, often I want to thank him and end the conversation.

My flow is the following:
[image: Flujo]

The open question is asked in the response of the intentions:
Q3_opinionservice -custom - yes
Q3_opinionservice -custom - no

[image: Pregunta abierta]

Thank you

Receive a text of an open question and end the conversation

Answer (score 0):

You may try and consider below approach.

In this approach, you will add a **Custom follow-up intent** on each of your `Q3_opinionservice -custom - yes` and `Q3_opinionservice -custom - no`.

The **Custom follow-up intent** will only contain one training phrase (any random sentences you want) and then annotate it as **sys.any** entity in which it matches any non-empty input as mentioned in this [Dialogflow System Entities](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/system-entities) documentation.

**My sample custom follow-up intent:**
[image]
**My sample conversation output:**

[image]